# How do I perform an Uber-Heart Transplant?

Tags: surgeon-simulator-2013

I have recently discovered why the Medic from Team Fortress 2 lost his medical license! Much to the Heavy's dismay, he was incapable of performing even the simplest of heart transplants.

[image]

As you can see, I was attempting to shatter the rib cage using a bat. It wasn't pretty, but it got the job done. I managed to successfully cut free each lung, the stomach, intestines, and yes, *eventually* the heart.

Unfortunately, I had a small accident. Unfortunately for the Heavy, I mean. I removed his heart, and upon attempting to find the replacement heart, I dropped his on the floor. I would've put his new heart in and left it at that, but I couldn't find it! I thought I looked everywhere.

**How do I replace this poor Heavy's <s>sandvich</s> heart?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen a let's play video of this:

Basically, find a tool to remove the ribs and organs.  (You seem to have done this already.)  Next, open the fridge.  There, you'll find 2 replacement hearts.  Choose the bigger one, and <strike>throw</strike> place it in the chest cavity.  Next, attach the *Überizer* to the replacement heart.  Poke it really hard if you have to.  Finally, position the *Medi-gun* such that it's pointing at the chest cavity.  You do this with the (finicky) joystick to the left.

And there you have it, another successful procedure.